# C++ 20 iteratos and g++ standard (std)

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, c++20

Well i just wanted to do a "foreach" like statement in C++, but in reverse order. Reading a little, the doc says that adding this to the "especial" form of the for statment it can be done.
Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vecInt;    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        vecInt.push_back(i);

    for (auto const& x : vecInt | std::views::reverse)    //Here is the problem with g++ -std=c++2a
    {
        
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that im using ubuntu linux with the latest g++ compiler.
According to what the compiler throws me. I put an "std=c++20", but it then told me: "Did you mean std=c++2a" so, i don't know what the "a" means, but i tought it would be the C++20 standard. And finally discovered that "std::views::reverse" isn't seen by the compiler.

To go to the point: i want to do a reverse "foreach" C++ statement and i can't.
Any help?

Comment: You need a more modern compiler, that's all. It works with [gcc10.1](https://godbolt.org/z/7EvKzs) and `#include<ranges>`

Comment: C++2a is the placeholder name for the first standard in the 2020s. It would be a shame to call it C++20 in 2018 and end up having it done in 2021.

Comment: Now my question to myself, i can't update ubuntu 20.04 g++ to the latest version. I will have to try someway to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucas You can clone gcc and compile it.

Comment: Thanks Ted i found a link that explains how to install the g++10 version. I have a slow connection, but i think it will succeed.

Comment: Woah!! it worked. Thanks guys!!

Comment: @Lucas That's fast! It takes a long time to compile gcc from a clean clone for me :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Dude might have a Cray.

Comment: @user4581301 I have an ABC800M :-)

Comment: @All hail the mighty Z80!

Comment: @user4581301 or no!!! the Z80 i emulated the NMOS 6502 and i did a Nintendo emulator in C. The Z80 what a great processor!! :-)

Comment: @Lucas I just realized that I have _two_ Z80A powered beasts in the attic with a DataDisk88 double 8" floppy drive with a total of 2 MB !!! :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Z80 drove the [audio in the Sega Genesis.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2ixZOgU2M0). The sucker was everywhere. Crays, not so much.

Comment: Guys, the Z80 rocked!! it was he first Gameboy main processor too.
I have an old book that covers 8086, Z80, 6502.